# decodeURIComponent Polyfill in pure js

Tags: javascript

I know "`decodeURIComponent`" is supported in every known browser , but i'm trying to understand it a bit better by trying to polyfill it .

there are many polyfills for `Atob`,`Btoa`.... but for some reason i didn't find any polyfill for "`decodeURIComponent`" any reason why?

Comment: Probably because it was defined with ES3 and has pretty much always been supported https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no polyfill because [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent#Browser_compatibility) has been supported since ES3.

The section ["URI Handling Function Properties"](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.3) of the EcmaScript Language Specification defines the algorithm for decoding a URI (`Decode`). It is an internal function that is called by both [`decodeURI`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.3.1) and [`decodeURIComponent`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.3.2). The latter two functions are really simple wrappers around `Decode` and only differ in which characters are considered "reserved". For `decodeURIComponent` it is simple: there are no reserved characters.

I have here implemented `Decode` and `decodeURIComponent` according to those specifications:

```js
function Decode(string, reservedSet) {
    const strLen = string.length;
    let result = "";
    for (let k = 0; k < strLen; k++) {
        let chr = string[k];
        let str = chr;
        if (chr === '%') {
            const start = k;
            let byte = +`0x${string.slice(k+1, k+3)}`;
            if (Number.isNaN(byte) || k + 2 >= strLen) throw new URIError;
            k += 2;
            if (byte < 0x80) {
                chr = String.fromCharCode(byte);
                str = reservedSet.includes(chr) ? string.slice(start, k + 1) : chr;
            } else { // the most significant bit in byte is 1
                let n = Math.clz32(byte ^ 0xFF) - 24; // Position of first right-most 10 in binary
                if (n < 2 || n > 4) throw new URIError;
                let value = byte & (0x3F >> n);
                if (k + (3 * (n - 1)) >= strLen) throw new URIError;
                for (let j = 1; j < n; j++) {
                    if (string[++k] !== '%') throw new URIError;
                    let byte = +`0x${string.slice(k+1, k+3)}`;
                    if (Number.isNaN(byte) || ((byte & 0xC0) != 0x80)) throw new URIError;
                    k += 2;
                    value = (value<<6) + (byte & 0x3F);
                }
                if (value >= 0xD800 && value < 0xE000 || value >= 0x110000) throw new URIError; 
                if (value < 0x10000) {
                    chr = String.fromCharCode(value);
                    str = reservedSet.includes(chr) ? string.slice(start, k + 1) : chr;
                } else { // value is ≥ 0x10000
                    const low = ((value - 0x10000) & 0x3FF) + 0xDC00;
                    const high = (((value - 0x10000) >> 10) & 0x3FF) + 0xD800;
                    str = String.fromCharCode(high) + String.fromCharCode(low);
                }
            }
        }
        result += str;
    }
    return result;
}

function decodeURIComponent(encoded) {
    return Decode(encoded.toString(), "");
}

// Demo
const test = "a€=#;ñàx";
console.log("test: " + test);
const encoded = encodeURIComponent(test);
console.log("encoded: " + encoded);
const decoded = decodeURIComponent(encoded);
console.log("decoded: " + decoded);
```